# How to stack up excel row to column

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a data [Data about world development indicators) which comes in the following format, is there any way to arrange in the following format for large datasets.

```
Country     1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995
Albania     639     349     218     381     619     761
Iran        2008    1923    2024    1993    1987    2070
UAE         27989   26946   26864   26141   26496   27974
```

I am expecting my final data format as

```
Albania 1990    639
Albania 1991    349
Albania 1992    218
Albania 1993    381
Albania 1994    619
Albania 1995    761
Iran    1990    2008
Iran    1991    1923
Iran    1992    2024
Iran    1993    1993
Iran    1994    1987
Iran    1995    2070
UAE     1990    27989
UAE     1991    26946
UAE     1992    26864
UAE     1993    26141
UAE     1994    26496
UAE     1995    27974
```

Comment: With a few lines of code using arrays, it is.

Comment: Please specify what should be done with data: transfer from Excel to Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data starts from 'A1' cell as like below screenshot.
Put below formula to `I1` cell then drag and down...

```
=INDIRECT("A"& CEILING((ROW()/6)+1,1))
```

Put below formula to `J1` cell then drag and down...

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,IF(MOD(ROW(),6)=0,6,MOD(ROW(),6)))
```

Put below formula to `K1` cell then drag and down...

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("A"& CEILING((ROW()/6)+1,1)),0,IF(MOD(ROW(),6)=0,6,MOD(ROW(),6)))
```

[image]

***Note:*** You have to modify formula if your put data starts different from `A1` cell.

Comment: Great! Thank you @harun24hr, this is what I need.

Comment: @Sudas Glad to know, it helps you.